# Maps between simply-connected Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the unit disc, complex plane, and Riemann sphere.  For each ordered pair of these surfaces, is there a surjective holomorphic map?  An injective holomorphic map?

Comment: Surely you can answer most of this question on your own.  Could you please elaborate on what parts you are stuck on?

Answer (score 4):

- Unit disk to complex plane:

  - Surjective? Consider $\sin((z+1)^{-3})$.  The cubing sends a $120^\circ$ wedge at $-1$ included in the disk onto a punctured neighborhood of $-1$, and $\sin(1/z)$ sends each punctured disk at its essential singularity onto the plane.
    Easier would be to use a linear fractional transformation to map the open disk onto the half plane with real part greater than $-1$, then square.
  - Injective? Yes.
- Unit disk to Riemann sphere:

  - Surjective? There is a surjective holomorphic map from the disk to the plane (see above) and from the plane to the sphere (see below), so yes.
  - Injective? Yes.
- Complex plane to unit disk:

  - There are no nonconstant holomorphic functions from the plane to the disk.
- Complex plane to the Riemann sphere:

  - Surjective? Consider $\frac{z^2}{1-z}$.
  - Injective? Yes.
- Riemann sphere to the complex plane or unit disk:

  - There are no nonconstant holomorphic functions from the Riemann sphere to the complex plane.  Removing $\infty$ from the domain would give an entire function with a removable singularity at $\infty$, which must be constant by Liouville's theorem.  (Or, note that the image of the sphere would be compact, hence bounded, hence the function must be constant by Liouville.)

Comment: Very nice, pedagogical answer, Jonas. For those who know the relevant jargon, Jonas's surjection of the complex plane to the Riemann sphere can be seen as  a (necessarily) ramified double cover of the Riemann sphere by itself with infinity deleted at the source.

Comment: @elgeorges: Thank you very much for the compliment and for the informative comment.